# How to promote an empty vector to a vector of one default element?

Tags: c++

Today I have this:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
if (foos.empty())
{
    foos.push_back(Foo());
}
```

I'd love to write something like:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos() || {Foo()};
```

Is there something handy like that, perhaps in Boost?

Comment: Write a function.

Comment: What's wrong with the original example?  IMHO, the first example is more readable.  Also, the compiler may apply optimizations anyway.

Comment: If `GetFoos()` returns a empty vector this is not the same as returning "false".

Comment: Would this not work? `std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos().size() ? GetFoos() : std::vector<Foo>(1);`

Comment: @Tas: Now you're generating the data twice.

Comment: IMO the original code structure is better than any "improvement" you could hope to make

Comment: This is true, so if `GetFoos()` does any kind of processing this is not an ideal solution. Well it's not an ideal solution anyway, because I agree the code posted is clearer. If `GetFoos()` simply returns a member this would work though, but then you're relying on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since resizing a vector to its existing size is a no-op, and since resizing it to be bigger than it already is will default-construct the new elements, you could do this:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
foos.resize(std::max(1, foos.size()));
```

However, I actually prefer your first example; it's much clearer and signifies intent.

But is there a one-liner? No, thank goodness.

Comment: inb4 monstrous proxy class and overloaded `op||`. But srsly just no

Comment: Challenge accepted:

`template <typename T> vector<T> operator||(vector<T> v, T t)
{
    if (v.empty()) v.push_back(t);
    return v;
}
`

Comment: But srsly plz just no

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there are enough tricks in the language to support the syntax

```
std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos() || {Foo()};
```

It will be better to write a function that clearly expresses your intent and use it.

```
void ensureAtLeastOneElement(std::vector<Foo>& v)
{
   if (v.empty())
   {
      v.push_back(Foo());
   }
}
```

and use it as:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
ensureAtLeastOneElement(foos);
```